# We want to generate synthetic data(large) from a small dataset using weka

Tags: time-series, weka, forecasting

Requirement: We want to generate synthetic data(large) from a small dataset using weka.

We need exactly the same as synthpop syn function does i.e. takes dataset as input and generate synthetic data. I tried Renjin but loading synthpop package is where the story stucked.

As much I have explored Weka has datagenerators i.e. Agrawal, BayesNet, LED24, RandomRBF, RDG1 . They generate random data.

Is there some method/classes in Weka similar to Synthpop

Please help me community.

Comment: Read the documentation first please http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/library/index.html

Comment: WekaForecaster forecaster = new WekaForecaster();
List<List<NumericPrediction>> forecast = forecaster.forecast(100, System.out);

WekaForecaster API serves the purpose what exactly I was looking for. It only forecasts numeric prediction. Can anybody help me in this regard ?